# Force socket close

Tags: windows, tcpip, sockets

Is it possible to close an established socket connection in Windows "manually" (e.g. using a command prompt tool)? I have several open sockets connected to a listening server, I can see them using `netstat`, and would like to close one of them manually.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check out TCPView, which is a GUI to do this stuff: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx

Comment: Only does ipv4 just as an FYI...

Comment: It seems like it supports ipv6 now in 2022.